# PHP: Uploading a MS word file on a form and sending via email

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, upload, ms-word

I am trying to create a form that has the option to upload an attachment (MS WORD) and send this attachment to an email address. I've gotten the form with basic values to work and successfully send, but I'm having trouble with PHP reading/processing the uploaded file.

These are the errors that I am getting:

> Warning: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs_form\upload\process-upload.php on line 15
>
> Warning: filesize() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs_form\upload\process-upload.php on line 16
>
> Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs_form\upload\process-upload.php on line 16
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs_form\upload\process-upload.php on line 17
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs_form\upload\process-upload.php on line 31

This is my PHP code:

```
$to = 'my@email.com';
$subject = 'PHP Scripting';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$message = "This email has an attachment.";
$upload = $_FILES['upload']; 
$upload_MIME_type = "application/msword";

$handle = fopen ($upload, "rb");
$data = fread ($handle, filesize($upload));
fclose ($handle);

$boundary = "---Multipart_Boundary---";

$headers = "/nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"" . $boundary . "\"";

$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

$text = "--" . $boundary . "\n" .
"Content-Type:text/plain\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
$message . "\n\n--" . $boundary . "\n" .
"Content-Type: " . $upload_MIME_type . ";\n name=\"" .
$upload . "\"\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data . "\n\n--" . $boundary . "--\n";

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $name <br>
Comments: $comments <br>
Email: $email <br>
EOD;

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($to, $subject, $text, $body, $headers);
if($success) {
    echo "The email was sent.";
} else {
    echo "The email was not sent.";
}
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction to figure this out.

Comment: `$_FILES['upload'];` is an array. If you are just reading the file directly (without moving it an uploads folder, you probably want `$_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']` which would have the name of the temporary file created with the uploaded data.

Comment: `$_FILES['upload']` is an array of values relating to the file you've uploaded, not the file itself. Most of the other errors stem from this. Take a look at [Handling File Uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: And thank you @HoboSapiens for the url reference :)

Comment: I would also just say that if a file is not uploaded that `$_FILES['upload']` won't have what you expect. You probably want to check that a file was uploaded first (the 'error' key should be 0 meaning no error).

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Good point I'll be sure to add that in..thanks again